# Grouping days depending on open hours

Tags: objective-c, loops

I have an array of items of a class `Time`. `Time` contains 3 properties: `weekDay` (range from 1 to 7, Sunday to Saturday), `openHour` (00h00 to 23h59) and `closeHour` (00h00 to 23h59).

I want is, given an array like this:

```
[{1, "10h00", "17h00"},
 {2, "08h00", "18h00"},
 {3, "08h00", "18h00"},
 {4, "08h00", "18h00"},
 {5, "08h00", "18h00"},
 {6, "09h00", "17h00"},
 {7, "09h00", "17h00"}]
```

write a list of days and hours like this:

> Sun: 10h00 - 17h00
>  Mon - Thu: 08h00 - 18h00
>  Fri - Sat: 09h00 - 17h00

I can easily write one line per day, but I don't know how to group days that have the same period (equal open and close hours). How can I create these ranges correctly?

Any pseudo-code will help me, but this will be implemented in Objective-C. If any one knows of a library or something that makes it easier on Objective-C, that would help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that could work. I was too lazy to create classes, but it should give you and idea of how to approach problem.

General idea is to iterate through all days, get values for each day, compare that to previous day and check if opening hours are the same.

To improve that best if you have isEqualToTime: method on your classes to compare that to previous time. And of course if you want to group it, change NSLog output to save group information into NSDictionary or whatever you want.

```
NSArray* rangeStartElement = nil;
NSArray* rangeStopElement = nil;

for (int day = 0; day < 7; day++)
{
    NSArray* valuesForCurrentDay = [openConfig objectAtIndex:day];
    NSString* currentFrom = [valuesForCurrentDay objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString* currentTo = [valuesForCurrentDay objectAtIndex:2];

    if(rangeStartElement == nil)
    {
        rangeStartElement = valuesForCurrentDay;
    }
    else
    {
        NSString* previousFrom = [rangeStartElement objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString* previousTo = [rangeStartElement objectAtIndex:2];

        BOOL isSameAsPrevious = [currentFrom isEqualToString:previousFrom] && [currentTo isEqualToString:previousTo];
        if(isSameAsPrevious)
        {
            rangeStopElement = valuesForCurrentDay;
        }

        if(isSameAsPrevious == NO || day == 6)
        {
            if(rangeStopElement)
            {
                NSLog(@"Day %@ - Day %@: %@ - %@",
                      [rangeStartElement objectAtIndex:0],
                      [rangeStopElement objectAtIndex:0],
                      [rangeStartElement objectAtIndex:1],
                      [rangeStartElement objectAtIndex:2]);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Day %@: %@ - %@",
                      [rangeStartElement objectAtIndex:0],
                      [rangeStartElement objectAtIndex:1],
                      [rangeStartElement objectAtIndex:2]);
            }

            rangeStartElement = valuesForCurrentDay;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

From what you said if you really want to have custom sorting, I would suggest to create a helper class like that:

```
@interface OpeningGroup
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* from;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* to;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* days;
- (BOOL) addTimeObject:(Time*) timeObject;
@end
```

Than you keep an array of those objects and try to add it to a group if "from" and "to" are same. return YES/NO depending if it succeeded. If none group was found - create a new one. Than you keep days in each group.
Later you just have to figure out how to display results, but should be easy.

Comment: That's a very good start, but in this case you assume that the `openConfig` array is sorted, which I can't guarantee (I could sort it, of course), but most important, it can't handle situations like (Mon, Wed, Fri) have the same open-hours, and (Tue, Thu) have a different. They wouldn't group. I believe I didn't make it clear enough in my question, but I can take it from here. Will mark as correct if no better answer shows up.

Comment: Hm I see. From question I thought you want to group only days which are close to each other. In case you want to group them in a custom way, best will be to have NSDictionary to group them.

Comment: Sorting will be easy if that's the only problem. Use NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"object.property" ascending:YES];